# Как получить int значение asset

Tags: java, android

Как можно получить int от файла?

```
    AssetManager am = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
    String[] files = am.list("my_images");
    ArrayList<Drawable> drawables = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String file : files) {
        showLog(file);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(am.open("my_images/" + file), null);
        drawables.add(d);

        iconsList.add(тут нужно добавить значение int от drawable d);

    }
```

Пытался сделать так, но не помогло, всегда возвращает 0

```
Resources resources = getApplicationContext().getResources();
final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(file, "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

Насколько правильно понял 0 т.к. файл лежит в `asset/my_images` как его получить?

Так пробовал тоже 0

```
Resources resources = getApplicationContext().getResources();
final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(file, "asset/my_images", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Идентификатора у файлов в каталоге `assets` нет. Цитата из [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html):

> Доступ к исходным файлам
>
> В редких случаях может потребоваться получить доступ к исходным файлам и каталогам. В этом случае просто сохранить файлы в каталоге res/ будет недостаточно, поскольку обратиться к ресурсу из папки res/ можно только по его идентификатору. Вместо этого ресурсы можно сохранить в каталоге assets/.
>
> Файлам, которые сохранены в каталоге assets/, не присваиваются идентификаторы ресурсов, поэтому вам не удастся сослаться на них с помощью класса R или из ресурсов XML. Вместо этого можно запросить файлы из каталога assets/, как в обычной файловой системе, и считать необработанные данные с помощью AssetManager.

Соответственно, метод [getIdentifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) не находит такого ресурса и возвращает дефолтное значение, т.е. 0